# problema con expresiones regulares, validar rango en php

Tags: php, base-de-datos

con una expresion regular que diseñe, la idea es que solo me deje pasar un rango numerico, como el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
if( empty($datos[RANGO_CUPOS]) ){
        $errorMensaje[$key+2][] = "El campo ".$arrayEncabezado[RANGO_CUPOS]." no puede estar vacío";
        $has_error = true;
    }elseif( !preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}-([0-9]{1,2})?+$/", trim($datos[RANGO_CUPOS])) ){
        $errorMensaje[$key+2][] = "El campo ".$arrayEncabezado[RANGO_CUPOS]." debe tener la estructura numero - numero";
        $has_error = true;
    }
```

mi problema es que me esta dejando pasar cosas como may-15, en la ultima parte no se como hacer la expresion regular de 26-. de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El `+` en esa expresión provoca un error, porque es un cuantificador, lo mismo que `?` (cero o uno del grupo anterior). Sin el `+` tu expresión debería validar `26-`, `0-4`, etc. y también resuelve el problema de letras. Puedes probar tus expresiones regulares en https://regexr.com/

Comment: funciono perfecto gracias por la ayuda